Non-linear, continuous, strictly increasing, unbounded function with a constant average rate of change?
I have a strictly increasing, continuous, non-linear, unbounded (above and below) function $w:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow{} \mathbb{R}$ such that for fixed $x,y\in \mathbb{R}$, it holds that for some positive constant $k_{x,y}\in \mathbb{R}_{++}$:
$\frac{w(x+a)-w(x)}{w(y+a)-w(y)}=k_{x,y}$ for all $a\in \mathbb{R}$.
I want to know if this implies that $x=y$. I know that functions that "repeat periods" that have linear envelopes would satisfy this if $x$ and $y$ are one period apart, and I am ruling out this type of function (also is there a name for this type of function?) I also know that $e^x$ satisfies this, but it is bounded below.
Suppose I don't know if $w$ is differentiable at $x$ and $y$. If it is the case that $x=y$, how would I go about proving this? I am stuck on this in my research.
Thanks!
